# Initializing an ActiveRecord object without overriding initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I quickly ran into problems when trying to create an ActiveRecord instance that overrode initialize like this:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lead
  def initialize(email = nil)
    self.email = email unless email.nil?
  end
end
```

I found [this](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html) post which cleared up why it is happening.

Is there anyway that I can avoid creation code like this:

```
e = Email.new
e.email = "info@info.com"
```

I would like to create and initialise my objects in one line of code preferably.

Is this possible?

Comment: ...and you don't like: `e = Email.new(:email => 'info@info.com')` ? `ActiveRecord::Base#new` is already way flexible allowing this or a block initialization form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
e = Email.new(:email => "info@info.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::Base#new also takes a handy block variation

```
email = Email.new do |e|
  e.email = params[:email] unless params[:email].blank?
end
```

The suggestions of using the hash version in prior answers is how i typically do it if I don't want to put any logic on the actual assignment.